# Main site search doesn't change URL on changed search

Tags: bug, search, stackexchange.com

When searching from the search box on [stackexchange.com](http://www.stackexchange.com/), when a search term is edited after the search results come up, the URL is not changed. This has the effect of after clicking a question and returning to the search page, the original search term results are displayed.

This behavior is different from other SE sites, including MSE, where the URL is changed to reflect an edited search term.

Below is an image of IE 11, but I see the same behavior in Chrome.

[image: example image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure that you were used to using Windows browser (which shows the full url automatically) and suddenly changed to a Mac (which doesn't shows the full url automatically)?

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq No Apple products were used.